# JavaScript display hour with a zero before it if it is less than 10

Tags: javascript, date, time, formatting

When using:

```
Date.toLocaleTimeString()
```

is there any way to have it display `01:42:35 PM` instead of `1:42:35 PM`?

I have tried adding in this:

```
Date.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', second: '2-digit'})
```

but it still only produces a single digit hour (unless it is after 10).

Comment: There is no *Date.toLocaleTimeString*, there is [*Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html#sup-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring) though. It's part of the internationalisation API and not supported by all browsers in use.

Answer (score 4):

If my reading is right, according to the [relevant spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html#sec-formatdatetime), it appears this is intentional.

> - Else if f is "2-digit", then
>
>   - Let fv be FormatNumber(nf2, v).
>   - If the
>       length property of fv is greater than 2, let fv be the substring of fv
>       containing the last two characters.

I can't understand why it would be specified that way, but there it is.  If you want to do zero-padding, it seems you'll just need to prepend it yourself.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for haha but it seems so. Thanks for finding that. All of my searches turned up nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It worked in this way for me

```
var datelocal = new Date(2016, 01, 01, 1, 1, 1).toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
hour: '2-digit',
minute: '2-digit',
second: '2-digit'
});
```

i'm also attached a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ozUypoKfUHqNdCX5lTpg?p=info).

**NOTE**: you have to provide new Date() instead of passing date parameters to Date method to get the current date.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. I just posted for simplicity sake. It still doesn't produce a 2 digit hour.

Comment: When I press the button on your plunker, I get "1:01:01 AM".  What do you get?  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString or similar functions to get the right format in such situations, I tend to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in my JavaScript project. Moment.js is a JavaScript library which is specifically designed to parse, validate, manipulate and [display](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) dates. To get a string for the time in the format you described, you could use:

```
var s = moment().format('hh:mm:ss A');
console.log(s);
```

This uses the current date. If you want to use another date, you can do so, too:

```
var s = moment(new Date(2016, 8, 19, 1, 10)).format('hh:mm:ss A');
console.log(s);
```

It saves you the hassle of doing your own zero-padding and other similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use "2-digit" in hour

```js
const options = {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'};

        function ut() {
            let d = new Date();
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString('de-DE', options);
        }
        window.setInterval(ut, 1000);
```

```css
#time {
            font-size: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            white-space: nowrap;
            color: black
        }
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Your hour still doesn't have a "0" at "8:47:08", but `hour: '2-digit'` have correct behaviour

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not read the question carefully, accept my apologies, please.